Siblings and a dog lose parents and journey to find relatives
Centered around a group of brothers and sisters (possibly including a dog). I vaguely remember that they lost their parents, and they had to journey to find relatives (I remember there was snow).
I watched this on TV in the 1980s, so it could be a movie from the 1960s or 1970s.
I think it's a Hollywood drama movie, could be an only-on-TV movie.

Do u remeber, Was that a "horror/comedy" movie?

It's a drama, makes-you-cry type...

Well, there goes my theory that it was Star Wars.

@MichaelStern: I can't remember there was a dog in Star Wars... I know there was a dog in Star Trek.


On Our Own (1988)

On Our Own is a 1988 family film about four children, Mitch, Kate,
  Travis and Lori. After being abandoned by their father and with the
  death of their mother they are forced to move into a children's home.
  Feared they will have to be separated, they escape to their old home
  where Mitch collects all the money he can find, and his Uncle Jack's
  address, thinking Jack will know where their father is. They also
  manage to get their dog back. They then get into their mother's old
  car and drive away, with neighbors spotting them. The police are now
  on their trail...(Edited from Wikipedia)

Browse through screenshots here and here. Check out some clips. Or, just watch the whole movie on YouTube :-)
--------------------EDIT-----------------------

Another possibility is The Beniker Gang (1985), similar in many ways to ''On Our Own''. Except this one features a group of unrelated orphans who, in order to escape from the foster care system, take off on a road trip.
As far as I could make out, the group don't ever travel through snowy terrain. Read a review; browse through some screenshots; two clips here and here. If you want to verify the scenes you mentioned, you might also want to check this link.

I don't think this is a movie I remember, now I remember that they journey through winter to move to a place...
Thank you, though..

@Josh Gandosh, first off, sorry for the late response - it's been a busy week at work :-) I've added another movie option to the original reply. Take a look, let me know :-)

Thank you, but unfortunately it's not the movie. But The Beniker Gang sounds a fun movie....
